# Binding to template-generated child element

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I'm trying to setup a parent control property one way binding so that it points to an attached property of the control instance used as the data template's visual tree root:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myns:HostedObjectType}">
    <myns:ChildControl myns:AttachedBooleanProperty="False">
        <!-- put whatever you like here -->
    </myns:ChildControl>
</DataTemplate>

(...)

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myns:OtherHostedObjectType}">
    <myns:OtherChildControl myns:AttachedBooleanProperty="True">
        <!-- put whatever you like here -->
    </myns:OtherChildControl>
</DataTemplate>

(...)
<myns:ParentControl
    Content="{Binding MyHostedObject}"
    SomeBooleanProperty="{Binding ???}"
/>
```

What would be the appropriate way to bind to that property **that will not require any kind of additional code on "hosted" classes** ?

(Please note that the example above is oversimplified on purpose)

Comment: What if multiple child have different values?

Comment: @RohitVats AFAIK data templates can only have one single root element.

Comment: Yeah but in case property is binded to some databound object like `<myns:ChildControl myns:AttachedBooleanProperty="{Binding SomeProperty}">`, it bound to have different value depending on the value of property.

Comment: `SomeBooleanProperty` binding would be one way only, so whatever binding would be set on the child's attached property would simply automatically update the property on the parent. Am I right?

Comment: It's OneWay or TwoWay that's dependent on the property registration. One question - Can you have multiple childs for parent control or just single child? (By child I mean how many instances of `HostedObjectType` will be created?)

Comment: Ideal solution would be to set property on parent control and let child control inherit them. Other way round doesn't seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: @RohitVats There's only one child control for `ParentControl` but it may host different content, each of which will have their own template. This is why I'd rather set the binding this way; I won't have to set it inside every other templates.

Comment: And value of `myns:AttachedBooleanProperty` will be different for different dataTemplates. In case yes then best solution would be to bind attached property to some bool property in your dataBound object and then bind parent control with that bool property. All other solutions would be hacky to use converter and get child element via traversing visual tree and getting the value.

Comment: `This is why I'd rather set the binding this way; I won't have to set it inside every other templates.` But you are setting it on every template (HostedObjectType and OtherHostedObjectType).

Comment: @RohitVats `But you are setting it on every template` In reality I am not, the above is oversimplified on purpose. The attached property will be set automatically through `PropertyMetadata` and thereafter changed depending on the UI's specifics.

Comment: Hmmm then only possible solution would be to bind with some property. Moreover, elementName as suggested in other answer won't work either because of some VisualTree constraints.

Answer (score 0):

To bind to an attached property of a `Control` you'll have to use `Path` and `ElementName` binding:

```
<myns:ParentControl
    Content="{Binding MyHostedObject}"
    SomeBooleanProperty="{Binding Path=(myns:AttachedBooleanProperty), Mode=TwoWay, ElementName="childControlName"}"/>
```

Also I would suggest to go the other way around: use `TemplatedParent` binding to get `SomeBooleanProperty` from `ChildControl`.

Comment: Ain't there a way to simply fetch whatever `DependencyObject` instance is set as the active visual tree root element for the template, regardless of its name? The thing is that I want the parent and the children to know as little as possible about one another. Relying on the element name feels like the parent would know too much. Same goes for using `TemplatedParent`: I don't want the `DataTemplate` assuming it'll be hosted in a `ParentControl`.

Comment: @Crono, You can use a specific converter which will get the `Content` and "unwrap" it to get `ChildControl`. Sounds a bit hacky, but you'll get your loose coupling.

Comment: So basically there's no easy / clean way to have it. I was hoping there was some kind of `RelatedSource` magic available to fetch the first element of a `DataTemplate` and that I just kept missing it. Oh well. :/